# ASP.NET Core 7 Authentication/Authorization middleware showing Microsoft login instead of custom application login page on serving static files

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, .net-7.0

I am trying to show a custom login page if user is not authenticated for accessing static pages which I am serving from `/staticfiles`
request path. I have called `useAuthorization()` and `useAuthentication()` middleware before serving these static files.
The problem is that I see the standard Microsoft authentication page as shown here:

[image]

instead of my custom login page despite of handling the event properly like below where I explicitly asks it to redirect to `/Login` page:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var fileExtensionContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
fileExtensionContentTypeProvider.Mappings[".yaml"] = "text/yaml";
fileExtensionContentTypeProvider.Mappings[".yml"] = "text/yaml";

var fsoptions = new FileServerOptions();
fsoptions.StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = fileExtensionContentTypeProvider;
fsoptions.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "staticfiles"));
fsoptions.RequestPath = "/staticfiles";

fsoptions.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
{
    if (!HttpContextHelper.IsAuthenticated(ctx.Context.User,ctx.Context))
    {
        // respond HTTP 401 Unauthorized.
        ctx.Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        ctx.Context.Response.Redirect("/Login");
    }
};

app.UseFileServer(fsoptions);
```

Also my OpenIDConnect middleware is wired correctly and works for all SAML requests

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = Configuration["AWS:ResponseType"];
                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["AWS:MetadataAddress"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["AWS:UserPoolClientId"];
                options.CallbackPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/externalauthentication/callback/");
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AWS:UserPoolClientSecret"];
                options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut;
            });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Am I missing something here? If no, then how can I write a custom interceptor which will intercept all requests for path containing `/staticfiles` and redirect to login page only if user is not authenticated?

Also if I inspect any URL that contains this path: "/staticfiles" then I get following:

[image]
As can be seen here ... its going to SAML Login via was cognito authorize request ... why and how is this happening despite of middleware configuration?

Comment: do you want to use an external authentication provider? if not, you may want to consider using Identity library instead for some convenient abstractions.  Something like `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` would give you what you want, after you scaffolded identity, just as a different approach (as long as it fits your needs)

Comment: I am already using Aws cognito as an idaas. The problem is that only for paths having 
keyword "staticfiles" are being redirected to Microsoft login instead of my application login page

Comment: do you want to login through your own website's `/Login` page? if so, why do you have OAuth or SAML in first place? I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Seems like you asked multiple questions too. regarding how to "intercept" `/staticfiles` requests, you can write a custom middleware. See my response for code

Comment: @EmreBener i use AWS cognito SDK for custom login and custom signup .. i am not using Cognito Hosted UI , because I need users to sign up with ADDITIONAL attributes so hosetd UI will not work for me. BUT I also use another option: Sign in with Microsoft on my custom login page that uses cognito SDK to sign in and sign up

The problem is that ONLY for staticfiles I am unable to redirect to my custom login page. Instead , Microsoft login page appears I don't know why .

Hope this clears my problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would write a custom middleware to "intercept" requests and manually check if user is authenticated for a specific path.

Custom middleware code (this is a class of its own):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/staticfiles"))
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Then, here is how you would register it in Program.cs:

```
// ...
app.UseAuthentication();

// Add the custom middleware
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
// ...
```

Lastly, make sure you configured authentication correctly:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        // Configure other options as needed
    });
```

Comment: i should place custom middleware before useAuthentication or after it ? ... because its UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() that sets : context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ... right?
If I check it before it will always give : IsAuthenticated false?

Comment: yes, correct. sorry for the oversight.

Comment: but @EmreBener ... Its UseAUthorization() middleware that is short-circuiting and my custom middleware is not being called at all ... so i logged entire request .. what I could see in logging is that all custom middleware are called , but the middleware after UseAuthorization is not called at all .. that is why its redirecting use MicrosoftLogin page because my custom middleware is not being executed. What should I do?